# Adding tracks to Zune library using C#

Tags: c#, .net, zune

Using C#, how do I programmatically add tracks to the Zune library?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there are APIs exposed - can you drop files into the monitored folders instead and let the groveler discover them?

Comment: That should work. But is there a way to find all monitored folders?

Comment: It depends on the OS.  For Win7 I believe it uses the OS monitored folders.  For XP it's probably stored in the registry.  I don't remember how vista works.